# Taskwarrior - How not to display the age of a task

Tags: taskwarrior

I am using taskwarrior together with conky and to make the format look nicer, I want to modify, what information is actually given by taskwarrior.
In particular, I do not want it to display the "Age" column of a task.
Right now it looks like this:

```
ID Age   Due Description        Urg 
 1 33min 1d  Do Stuff           8.33
```

but I want it to look more like this:

```
ID Due Description        Urg 
 1 1d  Do Stuff           8.33
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines to the file `~/.taskrc`:

```
report.report1.description=Report without age attribute
report.report1.columns=id,due,description,urgency
```

Then you can run `task report1` to view the report.

Comment: Thanks, this works!
One line I also added looks like:

`report.report1.filter=status:pending -ACTIVE -WAITING -BLOCKED -OVERDUE`

Otherwise also already done tasks will be reported as well.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to edit the default reports. With this command:

```
task show report
```

You will get the configuration of all the reports. The default report of `task` command is `report.next`, so you can put this in your `.taskrc` without `entry.age`:

```
report.next.columns=id,start.age,depends,priority,project,tags,recur,scheduled.countdown,due.relative,until.remaining,description,urgency
report.next.labels=ID,Active,Deps,P,Project,Tag,Recur,S,Due,Until,Description,Urg
```

Now the `task` command will show the `next` report without the `Age`.